# Why does YARG which is linked to JCenter is not accessible though maven?

Tags: maven, bintray, jcenter

Yarg library https://bintray.com/cuba-platform/main/yarg is linked to JCenter repository. When I try to check JCenter storage: https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/haulmont/yarg/yarg/ There are only old versions from Maven Central. Why does JCenter includes them?.

Why do new versions are not synced to JCenter? It seems that the new package is conflicting with these old packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for putting this into our attention.

With regards to the issue you describe, we have managed to find the root cause for it. 
There was a sync issue between Bintray and JCenter after approving the package to JCenter. Since that, new packages could not sync.

We hope this clarifies and resolves your enquiry.

Please let us know if you have any follow up questions.

Yonatan Brand, 
JFrog Support.